# PHP force header download not working on zip files

Tags: php

I have a document download site where I track files downloaded.

My problem is getting zip files to download through the script I am using. Every other file gets forced to download apart from zip files. When a zip file is pushed it just goes to the download.php page where the script is with no file being pushed out.

```
          ob_start();
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Expires: 0');
          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
          header('Pragma: public');
          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
          flush();
          readfile($file);
          exit;
```

Comment: Won't `ob_clean` discard the headers you had just set?

Comment: What kind of server do you have as well?

Comment: and what browser did you tried? one or more?

Comment: No point in buffering headers...

Comment: What actual headers are received when you test? (`wget -S` or FF Liveheaders, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that works for me:

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")) {
    header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_url).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_url));
} else {
    header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_url).'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_url));
}
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: Its on both firefox and ie. It works on my localhost but not on my production server which makes me think it could be my live server (shared hosting running Apache)

Comment: No errors and it does not even start to download. Just goes through to where the sript is and shows an empty page. As mentioned, its working on local host.

Comment: possible permissions issue, windows box?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, this quotes helped that time:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the `base_name` for the content disposition and length, I had the full path instead. Using `base_name` worked for me.